# How to access the value set in .then in my init function in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

How do I access $scope.email in $scope.init(). Currently it is giving me undefined.

```
      app.controller('someCtrl',
        [$scope,$http,$location,function($scope,$http,$location){
         $scope.init = function(){
          $scope.func1();
          console.log($scope.email); // giving undefined
     }

 $scope.func1 = function(){
      var data = {
       'Content-Tye' : 'application/json',
       'some-token' : $cookies.get('sometoken')
    };
    $http({
       method : 'GET',
       url : some url,
       headers = data,
       timeout: 50000

  }).then(function(successData){
     $scope.email = successData.entity.email;
  }).then($http({
     method:'GET',
     url: some url,
     headers: data,
     timeout:50000
  })
    .then ..)

  }

  }])
```

I have series of .then that confuses me. How do I wait until my $scope.email is set? My console.log statement gets executed before it is being set. How do I make it wait? I did read about promise, but what confuses is me multiple .then statements. I want to wait until first .then is completed to do console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait, then func1 will need to return a promise, and then you'll need to use that promise's `.then` function

```
$scope.init = function(){
  $scope.func1()
    .then(function() { // <--- using .then
      console.log($scope.email);
    });
}

$scope.func1 = function(){
  var data = {
    'Content-Tye' : 'application/json',
    'some-token' : $cookies.get('sometoken')
  };
  return $http({ // <--- notice the return
    method : 'GET',
    url : some url,
    headers = data,
    timeout: 50000
  }).then(function(successData){
    $scope.email = successData.entity.email;
  }).then(
    ... etc ...
  );
});
```

Also, if any of your `.then` functions are asynchronous and you want to wait for them as well, then make sure they return their promise.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for the answer. This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas beat me to it barely, and his answer will work, but if you don't care about the other .then's and just want to make sure the email has been set, then this will work for you.

```
app.controller('someCtrl',
    [$scope,$http,$location,function($scope,$http,$location){
     $scope.init = function(){
      $scope.func1().then(function() {
        console.log($scope.email); // giving undefined
      });
 }

$scope.func1 = function(){
var deferred = $q.defer();
var data = {
   'Content-Tye' : 'application/json',
   'some-token' : $cookies.get('sometoken')
};

$http({
   method : 'GET',
   url : some url,
   headers = data,
   timeout: 50000

  }).then(function(successData){
     $scope.email = successData.entity.email;
     deferred.resolve();
  }).then($http({
     method:'GET',
     url: some url,
     headers: data,
     timeout:50000
  })
    .then ..)

  }

   return deferred.promise;
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below code,

```
app.controller('someCtrl', [$scope,$http,$location,function($scope,$http,$location){
    $scope.init = function(){
       var data = {
         'Content-Tye' : 'application/json',
         'some-token' : $cookies.get('sometoken')
       };
       getEmail(data).then(function(response){
          $scope.email = response.data;
          console.log($scope.email);
          $scope.func1(data);
       });
    }
    function getEmail(data){
       return $http({
           method : 'GET',
           url : some url,
           headers = data,
           timeout: 50000
       }).then(function(response){
          return response.data.email;
       });
    }
    $scope.func1 = function(data){
       $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : some url,
            headers = data,
            timeout: 50000
       }).then(function(response){
           $http({
              method:'GET',
              url: some url,
              headers: data,
              timeout:50000
       }).then(function(response){
           // do something...
       });
    };
}]);
```